# React Router doesn't work

Tags: reactjs

I have built a simple app with React Router but when I try to launch that app, I get two errors in the console:

1. The prop `history` is marked as required in `Router`, but its value is `undefined`.
2. Cannot read property `location` of undefined

This is my code:

```
var React = require('react');
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');
var {Route, Router, IndexRoute, hashHistory} = require('react-router');
var Main = require('Main');

ReactDOM.render(
    <Router history={hashHistory}>
        <Route path="/" component={Main} />
    </Router>,
    document.getElementById('app')
);
```

and package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "boilerplate",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Simple React App",
  "main": "ext.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "Milad Fattahi",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.15.3",
    "react": "^15.5.4",
    "react-dom": "^15.5.4",
    "react-router": "^4.1.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.5.1",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.2",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.5.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.5.0",
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.24.1",
    "webpack": "^1.12.13"
  }
}
```

**Edit:**

I installed `react-router-dom` and changed third line of my code to this but nothing changed.

```
var {Route, Router, Link} = require('react-router-dom');
```

Comment: you are using **react router v4**, that has been changed completely. The way you wrote is for the older versions, use `react-router-dom`, check this for details:https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/quick-start

Answer (score 2, accepted):

with v4 ,you may also need to import **react-router-dom**. I haven't tested , but this should work.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { BrowserRouter, Route,IndexRoute, hashHistory } from 'react-router-dom'
var Main = require('Main');


ReactDOM.render(
<Router history={hashHistory}>
    <Route path="/" component={Main} />
</Router>,
document.getElementById('app')
);
```

Also , with v4,there is no need to import 'react-router' . **'react-router-dom'** will do that.

Comment: I defined BrowserRouter as Router and it worked. Thanks.